# Transform a list + list of lists into a list of maps

Tags: scala, list

How can I transform this:

```
List(a,b,c)
List(List(1,2,3), List(2,3,1), List(3,2,1))
```

Into this:

```
List(a -> List(1,2,3), b -> List(2,3,1), c -> List(3,2,1))
```

Comment: That's a list of tuples, not maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val list1 = List("a","b","c")

val list2 = List(List(1,2,3), List(2,3,1), List(3,2,1))

val res = list1 zip list2 // List((a,List(1, 2, 3)), (b,List(2, 3, 1)), (c,List(3, 2, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list_a = List("a","b","c");
var list_b = List(List(1,2,3), List(2,3,1), List(3,2,1));
var new_list = collection.mutable.Map[String, List[Int]]();
for( i <- 0 to list_a.length-1){
    new_list += (list_a(i) -> list_b(i));
}
```

First we define both lists based on the example provided in the answer.
Second, we define the new list we"re trying to generate.
In the for loop, we"re adding new items to the array, based on the definition provided above.

Comment: Please explain your code

Comment: @NinoFiliu, done. thanks!